# Kusto query issue with title keyword

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I assume `title` may be reserved word or similar but query below refuses to be parsed around `c.title`. Not sure what exactly the issue with query itself

```
AzureActivity
| where CategoryValue == "ResourceHealth" and ResourceProviderValue == "MICROSOFT.COMPUTE"
| where not (ResourceGroup startswith "DATABRICKS-RG")
| extend d=parse_json(Properties)
| extend c = parse_json(tostring(d.eventProperties))
| where c.cause == "PlatformInitiated" and not(c.title == "Live Migration")
```

Error shown

```
 SYNTAX ERROR

Query could not be parsed at '.' on line [6,48]

Token: .
Line: 6
Position: 48

If issue persists, please open a support ticket.

Request id: 6a4d4bae-41f6-43b4-9657-55fc435acab9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as `title` is a reserved keyword in the language, you could replace `c.title` with `c['title']`.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors

Comment: is there a list of reserved keywords documented somewhere?